# Editing protocol?

Tags: support, edits

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[How can I multiply and divide an array by a scalar, Assembly-C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710820/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-an-array-by-a-scalar-assembly-c)*

Do I put edits and updates before or after previous edits?

Answer (score 7):

Neither, just rewrite the question so it makes sense as a whole once you've rewritten it. If you need to expand things, do so.

You don't need to put edit: before anything you edited for instance. If we need to see the changes we can look at the questions revisions, all the tools to do that are built into the system. Nor do you need to keep previous versions of your question, we can access them if we need to by clicking on the question's edited link.

As to the specifics of your question, you seem to be asking multiple things, that's a fairly sure way to get your question closed as too broad. Instead ask about one thing, maybe the answers will clarify things in such a way that you won't need the other questions, or you might ask them in a different way.

Additionally try to avoid redundancy e.g.

> Please help, Thanks

or

> Hi

it's unnecessary and just makes the question longer.

And finally try to be specific about what's wrong

> the numbers don't come out right.

what does that mean. What would the numbers be if they did "come out right"? What actually happens instead?

Answer (score 7):

Right, so...

1. **Don't use your question as the place where you capture answers.**  Looking at your edit history, [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53710820/4) caught my eye straight away.  If you've answered your question, add it as an *answer*.
2. It's important that your question reads coherently and smoothly.  While I only mildly grumble at the existence of "EDIT" or similar footnotes, they at least maintain the coherence of the question.  However, every time you've edited your question, you lead off with "Hi" which breaks up the flow of reading the question.
3. It's important to recognize that **this is not a forum**.  Your edits read more like forum posts and updates and that's not what they're meant to be.  If you have *new* information to add, it should be added in; progress updates aren't really *new* information.

Lastly...order the edits in a reasonable fashion.  If you have new information to add towards the bottom of your post, then add it there.  If you have new information to add towards the top, add it there.  Just as long as it's coherent.